# Entering unicode character for Chi-Rho in LaTeX

Tags: symbols, unicode

I am in the middle of a very long document (which means I will not be able to switch to XeTeX or LuaTeX), and everything is close to done with the exception of a few missing symbols. The symbols all exist as unicode characters; for now, I'm working on the Chi Rho symbol. It exists as a unicode symbol, but it does not exist in the Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List. Does that mean that I cannot insert this character into my document in some way (other than trying to draw something)?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi_Rho

Comment: I understand what the Chi Rho symbol is and I know the unicode codepoints for it; the question is how to insert this as a symbol (and not a graphic). This is an example, since there are 3-4 of these that I need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can compile the ☧ symbol as a standalone PDF, with LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX, and include it.  This embeds the Unicode font you used into your PDFTeX document.  You can even copy and paste it.

First, compile this to `chiro.pdf` with LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX:  Upload it with your project as a graphic.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\tracinglostchars=2
\usepackage{libertinus}

\begin{document}
☧
\end{document}
```

You can then embed the document in PDFLaTeX.  This code with automatically scale the symbol to the height of a capital letter in the current font.

```
\documentclass{article}
\tracinglostchars=2
\usepackage{libertinus}
\usepackage{graphicx} % For \includegraphics
\usepackage{parskip}

\newlength{\capheight}

\newcommand\ChiRo{%
  \settoheight{\capheight}{P}%
  \includegraphics[height=\capheight]{chiro.pdf}}

\begin{document}
Chi-Ro: {\ChiRo}.

{\Huge A big \ChiRo}

{\footnotesize A small \ChiRo}
\end{document}
```

[image: Libertinus sample]

If you want to use the Unicode character ☧ in your source, you can add the lines

```
 \usepackage{newunicodechar}
 \newunicodechar{☧}{\ChiRo}
```

Comment: +1: Seems to be a very robust solution.

Comment: If I copy/paste this solution (the standalone portion) into a new document and run XeLaTeX, I get a single page of output with a question mark in it. What am I missing?

Comment: @KarlWolfschtagg You might be missing the latest version of Libertinus Serif. Version 7.020 has the glyph. You can substitute any other font that does; Libertinus was just an example.