# tipa-pdflatex Unicode character

Tags: tipa

My tags are follows:

```
\documentclass{book}
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage{tipa}

\begin{document}

\textschwa

\end{document}
```

And the output came as:

[image]

If I copy this characters from `PDF` and paste it in `MS-Word` file, it shows they key as `@`, but I need to show this character as same as output as in `PDF` file, please suggest... Note that I'm using `PDFLaTeX` to generate the output....

Comment: Did you try `alt+447` in Word?

Comment: You could consider switching to Unicode, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/224164/typesetting-phonetic-symbols-unicode-or-tipa for an extensive discussion. If you want to keep using the `\textxxx` style commands then then [answer by yannis](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/554502/) is relevant.

Comment: well the problem is that the glyph has the name `at` in the font, so if you would simply redirect the name to U+0259 all @ in your document would suddenly copy&paste as schwa. This means you need to write a manual cmap, that is not so easy and takes some time. If you want to do it: There are a few examples in the cmap you can use as starting point. But using an unicode engine is easier.

Comment: You can also declare a command in `hypertef` that sets the Unicode string which gets copied from the document.

Comment: @Davislor Sorry, can you please get back with more details? Please...

Comment: @MadyYuvi In my tests, it didn’t actually work.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Could also use the `mmap` format, I think?

Comment: @MadyYuvi However, [this method does](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/579973/61644)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The font you use does have misleading glyph names and therefore there are no good automated solutions for this, but you can explicitly overwrite the mapping on a character by character basis using `\pdfglyphtounicode`. In your case you only want the font generated by the tfm file `tipa10.tfm` and want to map the glyph named "at" to Unicode codepoint U+0259, so this translates to

```
\pdfglyphtounicode{tfm:tipa10/at}{0259}
```

This can be added anywhere in the preamble of your document, so you get

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tipa}

\pdfglyphtounicode{tfm:tipa10/at}{0259}

\begin{document}

\textschwa

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but still I copy the reverse `e` character from the generated `PDF` and copy into a `Word` file, I got the character `@` only...Anything wrong I did? Please suggest...I used `PDFLaTeX` to run your code....

Comment: @MadyYuvi Your system might be too old. At the beginning of the log file, which version of LaTeX is listed?

Comment: Here it is `This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (MiKTeX 21.3) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2021.8.23)`

Comment: @MadyYuvi A bit further down there should be a line starting with `LaTeX2e` and a date. That is the version of the format, could you send that? (The first line only lists the version of the engine.)

Comment: Sorry, hope you expect this `LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 4
L3 programming layer <2021-02-18>`

Comment: @MadyYuvi You can either update your LaTeX version or add `\pdfgentounicode=1` in your preamble.

Comment: Sir, it's working like a champ...Hats off to you...

Answer (score 2):

If possible, you should load a font that supports IPA symbols in LuaTeX or XeTeX.  In this example, I use New Computer Modern Book.  Others include Libertinus, dejaVu and Charis SIL.  The text copies and pastes as `əə`.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{newcomputermodern}

\DeclareTextSymbol{\textschwa}{TU}{"0259}
% Only needed if you are mixing in 8-bit fonts:
%\DeclareTextSymbolDefault{\textschwa}{TU}

\begin{document}

ə{\textschwa}

\end{document}
```

You can also use `tipauni`, which should be simpler.  (Not to be confused with `unitipa`.)

If you save that standalone PDF consisting of only a schwa, you can [include this PDF file in a PDFTeX document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/579973/61644) to get a Unicode schwa that you can copy and search for.  You might additionally want to make the Unicode character `ə` run this command, with `newunicodechar`.

If you really, truly need to extend PDFLaTeX to support `tipa` and make the result copy as valid Unicode, what you want to do is extend `mmap` to support the 8-bit T3 encoding that `tipa` uses.