# How to use specific symbol for observations in my math sheet?

Tags: tikz-pgf, fonts, symbols

I am writing a bachelor thesis and I want to mark observations or remarks with this symbol:

[image: remark symbol]

which is produced by this code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.25]
\filldraw[color=black] (0,0) circle (1.5cm);
\fill[color=white] (0,0) circle (1cm);
\draw[very thick](-3,0) .. controls (-2,2) and (2,2) .. (3,0) .. controls (2,-2) and (-2,-2) .. (-3,0)--cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I want to have this eye symbol on the left side of the paragraph to illustrate the observation process that I have made. It seems silly to me to input it in my thesis like a picture.

Does anybody know how to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Why would it be silly to include it as an image? I'd almost suggest that - compile your code into an image and include it as needed (perhaps a `\marginpar`) via a command.

Comment: Yes, do that ^^ (or save box) avoids reparse it every time.

Comment: Here is [an example of compiling a standalone PDF with TeX and embedding it in other documents.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/579973/61644) That will get you the same vector graphic. You can do this with a TikZ image as well as with a font.

Comment: Thanks guys! I used Davislor's suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is an alternative, you could use the icon provided by the `fontawesome5` package:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\begin{document}
\faEye 
\faEye[regular]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! Such a simple solution ♥